# Rolle's Theorem for Complex Functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

We know the Rolle's theorem in valid for a real-valued function. Why can't we have Rolle's theorem in the for complex-valued functions?

Comment: There is no way to order complex numbers. Only the absolute values can be ordered.

Comment: There are ways to order complex numbers (for example the lexicographic order), but there is no way to order the complex numbers that makes them an ordered field.

Comment: @Peter: Why ordering property is coming in the picture in connection with Rolle's theorem?

Comment: An intuitive way to understand Rolle's theorem deals with the fact that if the function starts increasing then it will decrease somewhere and if it starts decreasing, it will increase somewhere.

Comment: There is an analogue for polynomials (but not for analytic functions in general): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem

Comment: Well can the argument of the differentiable complex number be made to zero?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand, you want a theorem like

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a open set $\Omega$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ for $a,b \in \Omega$, then, there is $c$ on the segment $]a,b[$ such that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(c) =0.$$

This theorem is false because we can find a counterexample. Consider the holomorphic function $f: z\to e^{z}$. We have $f(0)=f(2i\pi)$ but the complex derivative, which is $e^z$, will never cancel. However we can have a kind of Rolle theorem which is the following (and it is a true statement)

> Let $a$ and $b$ two distinct points of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ an entire function such that $f(a) =f(b)$. There are two points $c_1$ and $c_2$ on $]a,b[$ such that $$\Re(f'(c_1))=0 \quad \quad \Im(f'(c_2))=0.$$

It is important to note that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not necessarily equal.

Comment: @Dubussy: I wanted WHY Rolle's theorem or the result that you mentioned is not going to be holding for complex function. I mean what makes a real-valued function to have Rolle's theorem, but complex function doesn't?

Comment: @Debdas Ghosh : The usual real Rolle's theorem is proved thanks to mean value theorem. This fully uses the natural order on $\mathbb{R}$. But $\mathbb{C}$ doesn't have an interesting order. That's a reason (probably there are others) why the statement doesn't hold. However my second statement is true and you can remark that we go back to $\mathbb{R}$ thanks to $\Re$ and $\Im$.

Comment: @Debussy - actually, the mean value theorem is proved USING Rolle's theorem. So using the mvt to prove Rolle is really circular reasoning.

Comment: @Debussy- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's one perspective. Below I've written a fairly well-known theorem sometimes called the Grace-Heawood theorem.

> Let $P(z)$ be a complex polynomial of degree $d\geq 2$, and suppose that $P(1) = P(-1)$. Then $P$ must have a critical point $z_0$ somewhere in the closed disk of radius $\cot(\pi/d)$ centered at the origin (and this bound is sharp).

You can interpret this as a Rolle's theorem for complex polynomials, since it guarantees a critical point "near" the points $1$ and $-1$, where $P(1) = P(-1)$. But the problem with this is we have to assume that we are dealing with polynomials of degree $d\geq 2$, and with that assumption comes the assumption that there are critical points to begin with. Also notice that as $d$ gets large $\cot(\pi/d)\to \infty$, so the critical point can actually be pretty far away from $1$ and $-1$. If you allow yourself to think of a holomorphic function as an "infinite-degree" polynomial, this would suggest the possibility of critical points being "infinitely far" from $1$ and $-1$. (Yes, I know this is more motivation than it is solid mathematics.)

As the example of $e^z$ shows that holomorphic functions need not have critical points at all, even if they are not injective. And this destroys any chance that a Rolle's-type theorem could hold for arbitrary holomorphic functions.

I think the best way to think about this is less something to do with complex analysis, and more something to do with working in real dimension $>1$. Topologically, simply a lot more can happen in higher dimensions. The exponential map $e^z$ discussed above is a non-trivial covering map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^\times$; this is made possible at least in part by the fact that there are connected, non-simply connected subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ like $\mathbb{C}^\times$ in the first place. This is not the case for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The problem is, in fact, with complex numbers, not higher dimensional real space. Rolle has a perfectly valid higher dimensional analog, if interpreted correctly. For example if a continuous function on the closed unit ball in three dimensional space is differentiable on the open ball and constant on the boundary (the sphere), then the derivative vanishes somewhere in the interior. There is no true analog to this in complex numbers.